# I want to <ImageView> to float on the right side of the <Button>

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have tried to add the image but its added right to the text of the button instead of extreme right position. Namely I want to float the image on the right.

```
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(
  new Image("Button.png")
);
final Button button = new Button("button", imageView);
button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: grey; -fx-border-radius: 5;");
button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
```

**update** : This is link of images i need and my current button design that needs to be improved. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9WmX.png

Comment: You may want to take a look at the answer of the [how to make a button with two (2) or more icons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902473/javafx-how-to-make-a-button-with-two-2-or-more-icons) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set custom layout to button's graphic here. Using `StackPane` is my choice for floating laying outs (like in css):

```
@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    Text text1 = new Text( "back to home" );
    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView( new Image( "pkg/images1.jpg" ) );
    StackPane stackPane1 = new StackPane( text1, imageView1 );
    StackPane.setAlignment( text1, Pos.CENTER_LEFT );
    StackPane.setAlignment( imageView1, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT );
    final Button button1 = new Button( "", stackPane1 );
    button1.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: grey; -fx-border-radius: 5;" );
    button1.setMinWidth( 400 );

    Text text2 = new Text( "holiday" );
    ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView( new Image( "pkg/images2.jpg" ) );
    StackPane stackPane2 = new StackPane( text2, imageView2 );
    StackPane.setAlignment( text2, Pos.CENTER_LEFT );
    StackPane.setAlignment( imageView2, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT );
    final Button button2 = new Button( "", stackPane2 );
    button2.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: grey; -fx-border-radius: 5;" );
    button2.setMinWidth( 400 );

    final Scene scene = new Scene( new VBox( button1, button2 ) );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: The above mentioned method is not present fot javafx button.

I want to use it as an ON and OFF button.Image will be set to green oval figure on extreme right of the button and vice versa for OFF condition.

Comment: @Aman, then you are using old version of JavaFX, namely version 2. In that version you need to add the padding to the setStyle(). See edit. However upgrading to version 8 is recommended.

Comment: Also to on/off button you may consdier to use `ToggleButton`.

Comment: I set the padding of the button,still image comes right next to button text @Uluk.

Comment: But there is no gap between the image and the right border, right?

Comment: @Aman, you may increase the space between text and image by button.setGraphicTextGap(40);

Comment: @ Uluk yes there is gap between them,because the image position depends upon the length of the text of button.I have say 5 buttons on my frame and each of have different button text length,then how can I set the default position of image for all the buttons on right side,it seems like its not possible with  button.setGraphicTextGap(40); method because of varied text length in each button.

Comment: @Aman Can you post your current view and the desired one as a screenshot images. You can use imgur.com for uploading.

Comment: Please check the above link